# chol2inv(chol(x)) and solve(x)

Tags: r, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I assumed that `chol2inv(chol(x))` and `solve(x)` are two different methods that arrive at the same conclusion in all cases. Consider for instance a matrix `S`

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(3*3), 3, 3)
S <- t(A) %*% A
```

where the following two commands will give equivalent results:

```
solve(S)
chol2inv(chol(S))
```

Now consider the transpose of the Cholesky decomposition of S:

```
L <- t(chol(S))
```

where now the results of the following two commands do not give equivalent results anymore:

```
solve(L)
chol2inv(chol(L))
```

This surprised me a bit. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chol` expects (without checking) that its first argument `x` is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and it operates only on the upper triangular part of `x`. Thus, if `L` is a lower triangular matrix and `D = diag(diag(L))` is its diagonal part, then `chol(L)` is actually equivalent to `chol(D)`, and `chol2inv(chol(L))` is actually equivalent to `solve(D)`.

```r
set.seed(141339L)
n <- 3L
S <- crossprod(matrix(rnorm(n * n), n, n))
L <- t(chol(S))
D <- diag(diag(L))

all.equal(chol(L), chol(D)) # TRUE
all.equal(chol2inv(chol(L)), solve(D)) # TRUE
```